# Why is my Order model giving me errors in BillingModule? (nestjs)

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a module called OrderModule, which imports Order model in the imports array:

```
// OrderModule, imports omitted
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Cart.name,
        schema: CartSchema,
      },
      {
        name: OrderItem.name,
        schema: OrderItemSchema,
      },
      {
        name: Order.name,
        schema: OrderSchema,
      },
    ]),
    ProductsModule,
  ],
  providers: [OrderService],
  controllers: [OrderController],
  exports: [OrderService],
})
export class OrderModule {}
```

In my BillingModule, I import the OrderModule, like so:

```
// BillingModule, imports omitted

@Module({
  imports: [OrderModule, SettingsModule],
  providers: [BillingService],
  controllers: [BillingController],
})
export class BillingModule {}
```

Inside the BillingService, I import the Order model like so

```
@Injectable()
export class BillingService {
  constructor(
    private settingsService: SettingsService,
    @InjectModel(Order.name) private orderModel: Model<Order>,
  ) {}
```

When I run the server, I get the following erorr:

```
[Nest] 25980  - 07/02/2023, 9:42:37 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BillingService (SettingsService, ?). Please make sure that the argument OrderModel at index [1] is available in the BillingModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is BillingModule a valid NestJS module?
- If OrderModel is a provider, is it part of the current BillingModule?
- If OrderModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BillingModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing OrderModel */ ]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@InjectModel(Order.name)` without having `MongooseModule` in the `exports` of the `OrderModule` to allow access to the `OrderModel` provider that comes from `MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: Order.name, schema: OrderSchema, },])`.

The other option is to add that specific `MongooseModule` into the `BillingModule`'s `imports`